# Nagios read() returned error 11 error

Tags: rhel, nagios

I am facing Nagios showing error

> "got read() returned error 11"

notification.

Answer (score 1):

You will find the answer within the standard include file:

```
/usr/include/sys/errno.h
```

Where you will find:

```
#define EDEADLK         11              /* Resource deadlock avoided */
```

I suggest you to increase the debugging level of `nagiosd` to try to get some more information on the conditions causing this `nagiosd` detected problem.

If you already did it, I suggest you to add this information inside your OQ to get better answers.